# Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [32773] should be listening)

Tags: java, scala, docker, testcontainers

I am trying to use https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala that is inherent from https://www.testcontainers.org/ as the following:

```
final class MessageSpec extends BddSpec
  with ForAllTestContainer
  with BeforeAndAfterAll {


  override val container = GenericContainer("sweetsoft/sapmock").configure{ c =>
    c.addExposedPort(8080)
    c.withNetwork(Network.newNetwork())
  }

  override def beforeAll() {
  }


  feature("Process incoming messages") {
```

When I run the test with the command `sbt test`, I've got the following exception:

```
15:22:23.171 [pool-7-thread-2] ERROR  [sweetsoft/sapmock:latest] - Could not start container
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [32775] should be listening)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:47)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.HostPortWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(HostPortWaitStrategy.java:23)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.AbstractWaitStrategy.waitUntilReady(AbstractWaitStrategy.java:35)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(GenericContainer.java:582)
```

The image is a local image:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sweetsoft/sapmock             latest              f02be90356e7        3 hours ago         664MB
openjdk                       8                   bec43387959a        11 days ago         625MB
quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk   0.2.3               64849fd2d464        3 months ago        10.7MB
```

The question is, why is it waiting for `32775` port? And for what is the port good for?

**Update**

Maybe this log will help:

```
15:47:47.274 [pool-7-thread-4] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Found Docker environment with Environment variables, system properties and defaults. Resolved: 
    dockerHost=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    apiVersion='{UNKNOWN_VERSION}'
    registryUrl='https://index.docker.io/v1/'
    registryUsername='developer'
    registryPassword='null'
    registryEmail='null'
    dockerConfig='DefaultDockerClientConfig[dockerHost=unix:///var/run/docker.sock,registryUsername=developer,registryPassword=<null>,registryEmail=<null>,registryUrl=https://index.docker.io/v1/,dockerConfigPath=/home/developer/.docker,sslConfig=<null>,apiVersion={UNKNOWN_VERSION},dockerConfig=<null>]'

15:47:47.275 [pool-7-thread-4] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Docker host IP address is localhost
15:47:47.277 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.InfoCmdExec@51a07bb5
15:47:47.389 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.VersionCmdExec@70fc9b37
15:47:47.392 [pool-7-thread-4] INFO org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 18.09.6
  API Version: 1.39
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
  Total Memory: 7976 MB
15:47:47.395 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd - Cmd: ListImagesCmdImpl[imageNameFilter=quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3,showAll=false,filters=com.github.dockerjava.core.util.FiltersBuilder@0,execution=com.github.dockerjava.core.exec.ListImagesCmdExec@562a343]
15:47:47.417 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.RegistryAuthLocator - Looking up auth config for image: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3
15:47:47.417 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.RegistryAuthLocator - RegistryAuthLocator has configFile: /home/developer/.docker/config.json (does not exist) and commandPathPrefix: 
15:47:47.418 [pool-7-thread-4] WARN org.testcontainers.utility.RegistryAuthLocator - Failure when attempting to lookup auth config (dockerImageName: quay.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.2.3, configFile: /home/developer/.docker/config.json. Falling back to docker-java default behaviour. Exception message: /home/developer/.docker/config.json (No such file or directory)
15:47:47.418 [pool-7-thread-4] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.auth.AuthDelegatingDockerClientConfig - Effective auth config [null]
```

Comment: I believe that is from **Ryuk**, which is a helper container they use for cleaning. Are you running on Windows or on Linux?

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: When I try to run Ryuk https://gist.github.com/bifunctor/07a92ae70810bd7be8ab04a7b0ccb1ab, I've an error message

Comment: It seems that you do not have docker running. Try `sudo systemctl status docker` to check if the daemon is running and if it have problems. And `sudo systemctl restart docker` to restart it.

Comment: The docker service is running. I do not know, why the message appears.

Comment: Uhm... sorry, no more ideas on my part. Hope someone knows what is happening. You may also try asking directly to them, I believe they have a slack group or open a new issue.  Anyways, make sure you have the latest version of Docker and that you are able to run normal containers.

Comment: But anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Original java library has answer to your port question.
https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/

> Note that this exposed port number is from the perspective of the
>   container.
>
> From the host's perspective Testcontainers actually exposes this on a
>   random free port. This is by design, to avoid port collisions that may
>   arise with locally running software or in between parallel test runs.
>
> Because there is this layer of indirection, it is necessary to ask
>   Testcontainers for the actual mapped port at runtime. This can be done
>   using the getMappedPort method, which takes the original (container)
>   port as an argument

In Scala library you can get this mapped port by calling

```
container.mappedPort(yourExposedPort)
```

Error is most likely related to this concept, you need to expose that port in advance, inside your docker image. Make sure that you either have `expose 8080` command somewhere in your dockerfile or any image that is used to build yours have it

Comment: Hi @Smerk, I'm experiencing the same issue above. I added   expose: - "1523" in my docker-compose.yml but I'm still getting the same error. How can I solve the problem?